# Flutter: can I enable/disable InkWell in ListView builder?

Tags: flutter, listview

I working on education app (Something like udemy app)
In lecture list screen, I use Inkwell to show lecture data card, and onTap (when user click on card) it will go to video player page

[Lecture list page image HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxPxY.png)

When lecture list screen loaded:
First I have function to check number of views with http.POST for every lecture
If lecture views less than 2 views I want to make lecture card clickable (user can view lecture one more time)

but if user has views number equal 2 I want to disable the lecture, to prevent user to make another view

I think to use if statement to check number of views then enable Inkwell onTap property or not, but it's doesn't work

I need help about how I can do this situation

## =======================
views count function

```
checkViewsCount() async {
                        var XX = await checkLessonViews(lesson.id.toString(), lesson.lessonType);

                        if(int.parse(XX) >= 2){
                          //////////////////Here want to make lecture card disabled
                        } else {
                          //////////////////Here want to make lecture card enabled
                        }

                      }
```

## ============================
and this is InkWell code

```
return InkWell(

                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _activeLesson = lesson;
                          });
                          lessonAction(lesson);
                        },

                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
                              width: double.infinity,
                           child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  //////////////////////// Lesson No.
                                  Expanded(
                                      flex: 2,
                                      child: Customtext(
                                        text: lessonCount.toString(),
                                        fontSize: 16
                                      )),
                                  //////////////////////// Lesson title
                                  Expanded(
                                      flex: 8,
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Customtext(
                                            text: lesson.title,
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                            colors: kTextColor,
                                            fontWeight:
                                            FontWeight.bold,
                                          ),
                                          getLessonSubtitle(lesson),
                                        ],
                                      )),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Divider(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var canAddLecture = true;

if(int.parse(XX) >= 2){
  canAddLecture = false;
} else {
  canAddLecture = true;
}
```

and in onTap:

```
onTap: () {
   if(canAddLecture == false) return;
   setState(() {
       _activeLesson = lesson;
   });
   lessonAction(lesson);
}
```

Comment: You made my day, Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable inkwell in flutter, use an if condition to either display an inkwell or a container (without gesture handling properties) depending on the number of views the user has.